# File switcher sidebar in Notepad++ 5.5

Tags: notepad++, sidebar

I would like to know how to get a vertical file switcher on the left side i.e. in the left sidebar in Notepad++ 5.5?

I would like to have something like this as shown from the gedit editor?

[image: Gedit Files sidebar]

Answer (score 10):

You need to enable the 'Document Switcher' in the Peferences->General tab (it's a check box).

Once it's been enabled you should be able to just drag the window by the title bar onto the left side (it can be a bit fiddly for NP++ to detect the new location).

Comment: Nope that doesn't work. I would like to see the files in sidebar as we see in gedit, eclipse other editors and IDEs, etc

Comment: You want the file Tabs on the left? Do you mean the Preferences setting General->Tab bar->Vertical? If not please post a screenshot.

Comment: No that is not I am looking for. That looks ugly, the tabs get 90 degree oriented. I need as shown as in the screenshot. Please check

Comment: If the document switcher is not what you're looking for try the Window Manager plug-in (although I'm not sure it's supported any more).

Comment: I would have thought this solution should have worked even in NP++ 5.5. However, there are two (unrelated) "Document Switcher" settings. As snowdude mentions: Preferencs > General > Document Switcher > Show (Check this) should enable a docked side panel (on the left) with a list of your open documents. However, Preferences > MISC. > Document Switcher > Enable, enables the Ctrl+TAB functionality which results in a popup window that cannot be docked (and not so good if you have _a lot_ of documents open).

Comment: Bless you @snowdude.  I've been using NP++ for years and never noticed this option.  It's immensely helpful, exactly what I was searching for.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

As of Notepad++ 7.5.1:

"Settings" menu > Preferences > General (left side of pane) > Document List Panel section > "Show" checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

In Notepad++ v6.6.3, Settings > General > "List" Panel > check "Show under Document".

Comment: This worked great for me, but I wish there was a hotkey! :>

Answer (score 0):

do you mean f ile explorer? there's a plugin you have to install first: plugins > plugin-manager > Show Plugin Manager, then search for 'Explorer' and install it. after restarting notepad++ go to plugins > explorer and check "explorer".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer #2, you can use this plugin:

Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager > select "Explorer" > Install.

The Explorer plugin will show your filesystem, rather than a list of open files (which is redundant because the open files are shown in the tabs at the top).

Comment: I posted this answer because I was looking for the Explorer plugin on google, and this question was the first result to my search query.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Snowdude's answer, updated for v7.5.9 (64-bit)

Select on the menu:

Settings >> Preferences >> General >> Document List Panel >> Check "Show"

[From the Notepad Wiki - The Vertical File Switcher](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Document_Management#The_Vertical_File_Switcher)